# Move child id to parent id in jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a below input JSON and need to convert it to output JSON via jolt.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "A": "value1",
  "B": "value2",
  "C": {
    "D": "x1",
    "E": "x2"
  }
}
```

**Output** :

```json
{
  "A": "value1",
  "B": "value2",
  "E": "x2",
  "C": {
    "D": "x1"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the jolt specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `E` from the sub document and put it into the root document.

Jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "C": {
          "E": "[&2].&",
          "*": "[&2].C.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "A": "value1",
    "B": "value2",
    "C": {
      "D": "x1",
      "E": "x2",
      "F": {
        "a": "x1",
        "x": {
          "y": 1
        }
      },
      "H": "x4"
    }
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "A": "value1",
    "B": "value2",
    "C": {
      "D": "x1",
      "F": {
        "a": "x1",
        "x": {
          "y": 1
        }
      },
      "H": "x4"
    },
    "E": "x2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could we also rename the column "E"?

Comment: @TJJ yes, change "E": "[&2].&" to e.g. "E": "[&2].T"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this **`jolt`** spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "A": "A",
      "B": "B",
      "C": {
        "E": "E",
        "@D": "C.D"
      }
    }
  }]
```

**`Output:`**

```
{
  "A" : "value1",
  "B" : "value2",
  "C" : {
    "D" : "x1"
  },
  "E" : "x2"
}
```

Comment: I have complex json like below

[
  {
    "A": "value1",
    "B": "value2",
    "C": {
      "D": "x1",
      "E": "x2",
      "F": {
        "a": "x1",
        "x": {
          "y": 1
      }
      },
      "H": "x4"
    }
  }
]

Comment: could you suggest the jolt spec for above json structure. In "C" i have more complex json structure and need something generic wildcard(e.g *) so that i don't have to specify every column